# Optimization with Constraints using Alternating Direction of Method of Multipliers

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have an optimization problem of the form:

\begin{align*}
\text{minimize} &\quad f(x) + g(x) \\
\text{such that} & \quad Ax = b
\end{align*}

Where $f,g$ are both convex (but not differentiable), and I know the proximal operators for $f,g$ separately.

From reading [Parikh and Boyd](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/prox_algs.html), this problem looks almost exactly like the kind solved by the Alternating Direction of Method of Multipliers (ADMM, aka Douglas-Rachford splitting).  Indeed, my problem almost exactly matches section 4.4 in the this text, except in the text, it is not constrained.   It is just:

\begin{align*}
\text{minimize} &\quad f(x) + g(x) \\
\end{align*}

In fact, in equation 4.9, they show that ADMM is equivalent to the idea of an augmented Lagrangian, which they derive by adding a constraint:

\begin{align*}
\text{minimize} &\quad f(x) + g(z) \\
\text{such that} & \quad x = z
\end{align*}

But I would like to add my own constraint, and I do not know how to do that.

I believe this is possible, because there is a popular work called [Robust PCA](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/RobustPCA.pdf), where they modify the augmented Lagrangian to add their own constraint.  But their case seems quite different from mine, as they are optimizing over two variables (which nicely match up with the $x$ and $z$ in the augmented Lagrangian formulation), but I am not.

How can I use ADMM to solve my problem?  If it is not possible, is there a more suitable method?

Comment: Since your equality constraint is convex, can you just write it as $Ax=b$? This will be more clear.

Comment: Okay, I will edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using ADMM, then you should read [this paper by Boyd et al.](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf)

The first form that the paper deals with is: 
$$\begin{align*}
\text{minimize} &\quad f(x) + g(z) \\
\text{subject to} & \quad Ax + Bz = c.
\end{align*}$$
Your problem can easily be written under this form:
$$\begin{align*}
\text{minimize} &\quad f(x) + g(z) \\
\text{subject to} & \quad \begin{bmatrix}A \\ I\end{bmatrix}x + \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ -I\end{bmatrix}z = \begin{bmatrix}b \\ 0\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

One approach using the Douglas-Rachford method (which can be viewed as being a special case of ADMM) is to reformulate your problem as minimizing $$
\underbrace{f(x) + g(y)}_{F(x,y)} + I_C(x,y),$$ where $C=\{(x,y)\mid Ax=b, x=y\}$.

You can now minimize $F(x,y) + I_C(x,y)$ using the Douglas-Rachford method. Because $F$ is a *separable* sum of $f$ and $g$, evaluating the prox-operator of $F$ reduces to separately evaluating the prox-operators of $f$ and $g$.  Evaluating the prox-operator of $I_C$ requires projecting onto $C$, which is just a linear algebra problem.

Comment: Thank you!  However, I know the proximal operator of $f$ and of $g$, but not of $f+g$.  Is that a problem?

Comment: Because $F$ is a *separable* sum of $f$ and $g$, evaluating the prox-operator of $F$ reduces to separately evaluating the prox-operators of $f$ and $g$. So there is no problem.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much.  Also, what do you mean by the "consensus trick to handle the sum of three terms" in your first approach?

Comment: I think re-writing the objective as a non-separable function (here $I_C(x,y)$) will not benefit from the known convergence properties of ADMM for convex separable functions.

Comment: @Khue The Douglas-Rachford method minimizes functions of the form $F(u) + G(u)$, where $F$ and $G$ have prox-operators that can be evaluated efficiently. I have put the problem into this form, with $F(x,y) = f(x) + g(y)$ and $G(x,y) = I_C(x,y)$. As discussed in Boyd's Proximal Algorithms monograph, the Douglas-Rachford method can be viewed as being a special case of ADMM.

Comment: @Khue I edited my answer to try to clarify this.

Comment: @The_Anomaly I decided to omit the consensus trick comment from this answer, but Boyd explains it in either his ADMM monograph or in Proximal Algorithms. Basically you can minimize $\sum_i f_i(x)$ by reformulating the problem as minimizing $\sum_i f_i(x_i)$ subject to the constraint that $x_1=⋯=x_n$, and then applying Douglas-Rachford or ADMM in a straightforward way. It's a very useful trick to know about.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that you reformulated the problem with respect to the joint variable $u=(x,y)$. Since $F,G$ and $C$ are all convex, this is indeed an alternative way to do (it's a bit more complicated than my solution but worth to try both to see which one gives best results in practice).